# Using bit manipulation to tell if an unsigned integer can be expressed in the form 2^n-1

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

To test if an unsigned integer is of the form `2^n-1` we use:

```
x&(x+1)
```

What is that supposed to equal? That is,

```
x&(x+1) == ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In complement to the existing answers, here is a short explanation of why numbers `x` that are not of the form `0b00000` (zero) or `0b0111..11` (all lowest digits set, these are all the numbers 2^n-1 for n>0) do not have the property `x&(x+1) == 0`.

For a number `x` of the form `0b????1000..00`, `x+1` has the same digits as `x` except for the least significant bit, so `x & (x+1)` has at least one bit set, the bit that was displayed as being set in `x`. By way of shorter explanation:

```
x       0b????1000..00
x+1     0b????1000..01
x&(x+1) 0b????10000000
```

For a number `x` of the form `0b????10111..11`:

```
x       0b????10111..11
x+1     0b????110000000
x&(x+1) 0b????10000..00
```

In conclusion, if `x` is not either zero or written in binary with all lowest digits set, then `x&(x+1)` is not zero.

Answer (score 7):

A number of the form `2^n-1` will have all of the bits up to the nth bit set.  For example, `2^3-1` (7) is:

```
0b0111
```

If we add one to this, we get 8:

```
0b1000
```

Then, performing a bitwise and, we see that we get zero, because no bit is set on in both numbers.  If we start with a number not of the form `2^n+1`, then the result will be nonzero.

Comment: I think you meant `2^n-1` at the beginning

Comment: While you and the other answerer do a good job of explaining why it's necessary that `x&(x+1)==0` for `x` to be of the form `2^n-1`, neither of you even allude to the sufficiency of the property. Or in other terms, why can't a number `x` that is not written `0b0111..11` not have the property `x&(x+1)==0` ?

Comment: @Pascal:  If you'd like to answer and go into greater detail, I'd be happy to upvote such an answer.  :-)

Comment: @James I went ahead and drafted a short explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Zero. If X is 2^N-1, it is an unbroken string of 1's in binary. One more than that is a 1 followed by a string of zeroes same length as X, so the two numbers have no 1 bits in common in any location, so the AND of the two is zero.